# How would I align circles horizontally using loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, html5-canvas

I have managed to get the circles on top of each other but I have no clue how to make a line of circles that do not overlap.

This is what I have gotten so far.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
    fillCircle(200,200,i*20)
}

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = 100;

function fillCircle(x, y, radius) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: Oops! I originally answered your question showing vertical alignment. I see you want horizontal alignment and have edited my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The x-value of any next circle must be at least be the sum of the current and next circle radii beyond the current circle's x-value.

**So if:**

```
var currentCircleX=20
var currentCircleRadius=15
var nextCircleRadius=25
```

**Then:**

```
var nextCircleX = currentCircleX + currentCircleRadius + nextCircleRadius
```

**But if you are also stroking the circles:**

Since a context stroke will extend half-outside the defined path, you must also add half the lineWidth for each circle to avoid the circles touching:

```
// account for the lineWidth that extends beyond the arc's path
var nextCircleX = 
    currentCircleX + currentCircleRadius + nextCircleRadius + context.lineWidth
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
var currentCircleX=0;
var currentCircleRadius=0;

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var nextCircleRadius=i*20;
  var nextCircleX=currentCircleX+currentCircleRadius+nextCircleRadius;   
  fillCircle(nextCircleX,200,nextCircleRadius);
  currentCircleX=nextCircleX;
  currentCircleRadius=nextCircleRadius;
}


function fillCircle(x, y, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```